# C++CLI bug, stacking trackbars (weird visual effect and crash)

Tags: winforms, drop-down-menu, c++-cli, trackbar

I really need help with this but nobody is giving me any information. So I thought I'd just make a really long post detailing the issue and my code. Just as starting info this is a C++ DLL that loads the form upon loading into another program or being forcefully injected.

So first off I am stacking some trackbars. Depending on the selection of a dropdown box menu, certain trackbars will appear and some will go. Each trackbar has individual values. The best way to represent it is like a class.

Player1 -> R, G, B Trackbars
Player2 -> R, G, B Trackbars

So each player has 3. Switching players in the dropdown causes these to switch. So laying it out on the designer like so:

[image]

It doesn't show too well but they will be directly over eachother and switch each time. In the designer you will obviously only be able to see 3 as the others are underneath the top one.

I create them like so:

```
        this->trackbar_TeamBlue->Location = System::Drawing::Point(491, 225);
        this->trackbar_TeamBlue->Maximum = 255;
        this->trackbar_TeamBlue->Name = L"trackbar_TeamBlue";
        this->trackbar_TeamBlue->Size = System::Drawing::Size(153, 45);
        this->trackbar_TeamBlue->TabIndex = 10;
        this->trackbar_TeamBlue->Visible = false;
```

This is the same with each one. On the initialisation of the form I set all the Team trackbars to not visible and all the enemy trackbars to visible:

```
        trackbar_TeamRed->Visible = 0;
        trackbar_TeamGreen->Visible = 0;
        trackbar_TeamBlue->Visible = 0;

        trackbar_EnemyBlue->Visible = 1;
        trackbar_EnemyGreen->Visible = 1;
        trackbar_EnemyRed->Visible = 1;
```

The dropdown box menu is most likely not causing the issue but it is created like this anyway:

```
        this->dropdown_ESPColour->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ScrollBar;
        this->dropdown_ESPColour->FormattingEnabled = true;
        this->dropdown_ESPColour->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(4) { L"Enemy", L"Team", L"Weapons", L"Bomb" });
        this->dropdown_ESPColour->Location = System::Drawing::Point(353, 177);
        this->dropdown_ESPColour->Name = L"dropdown_ESPColour";
        this->dropdown_ESPColour->Size = System::Drawing::Size(121, 21);
        this->dropdown_ESPColour->TabIndex = 0;
        this->dropdown_ESPColour->Text = L"Enemy";
```

So basically, whenever the index 0 is selected with the dropdown I went the TeamRed set of trackbars to be usable. And index 1, the TeamBlue trackbars to be usable. I decided to make a very simple function to switch between these if the dropdown selection is changed.

```
System::Void dropdown_ESPColour_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    if (dropdown_ESPColour->SelectedIndex == 0) {
        trackbar_EnemyBlue->Visible = 1;
        trackbar_EnemyGreen->Visible = 1;
        trackbar_EnemyRed->Visible = 1;

        trackbar_TeamRed->Visible = 0;
        trackbar_TeamGreen->Visible = 0;
        trackbar_TeamBlue->Visible = 0;

    }
    else if (dropdown_ESPColour->SelectedIndex == 1) {
        trackbar_EnemyBlue->Visible = 0;
        trackbar_EnemyGreen->Visible = 0;
        trackbar_EnemyRed->Visible = 0;

        trackbar_TeamRed->Visible = 1;
        trackbar_TeamGreen->Visible = 1;
        trackbar_TeamBlue->Visible = 1;

    }
}
```

So building this form works fine. Loading it into a program or any other method works fine. Here is an image of the actual form loaded:

[image]

As you can see that works all fine and dandy. Keep note I havent changed anything as of now. That is what the form loads into. I can change all the values on these trackbars. Now trying to change to the other category, you will see that a weird visual effect occurs, a simple greyed out box with no slider appears. In the image you cant see the grey box but I can assure you, it is 100% there. For some reason the bars look white on these images and not on my screen.

[image]

Whenever I click on this greyed out area where they are suppose to be the form crashes. If I change the dropdown box back then they appear back again and work fine. Does anybody know what could be causing this issue?

Comment: `Whenever I click, the form crashes`: We can do nothing without knowing what the crash is. Include the exception name, the stack trace, etc.

Comment: Why not keep the same trackbar visible the whole time, and have the `trackbar_changed` event look at the dropdown to see which thing to modify?